# How do I enable a button after the scrollbar goes to the bottom?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jscrollpane

So, I used a `JScrollPane` and then I added a `JTextArea`. I used `textArea.setCaretPosition(0)` to reset the scroll and it went at the top. All good, until I wanted to set a disabled Button on enable when the scrollbar reaches at the bottom.

How can I do that?

Comment: *All good, until I wanted to set a disabled Button on enable when the scrollbar reaches at the bottom.* - why do you care where the scrollbar is? If the scrollbar is halfway down and the user decides they want to go back to the top, why should you stop them? Let the user decide when they want to use the button, not you.

Comment: @camickr An "Accept" button is usually disabled until the entire terms of agreement are scrolled.  They may not be read, but scrolled.  To the OP, you have to get the vertical scrollbar position and see if it's near the maximum value.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, the OP doesn't mention an "Accept" button anywhere. The functionality of the button is to scroll to the top. How does scrolling to the top confirm the entire agreement has been browsed? The user could use the scrollbar manually to go back to the top. The OP needs to clarify the question, which is why I asked for more information. I don't want to make assumptions.

Comment: Hi, sorry for this late answer. Also I'm sorry if the question was not clear to you, I will look forward to correct that in the upcoming questions that I will ask. Gilbert Le Blanc was right. All of this is about an accept button for the "Terms of agreement". @camickr I have never mentioned that the functionality of the button is to scroll to the top. Sorry for the missing information. Thank you.

Comment: @NewBegin, *I have never mentioned that the functionality of the button is to scroll to the top* - you stated " I used textArea.setCaretPosition(0) to reset the scroll and it went at the top. All good, until I wanted to set a disabled Button" - why would you mention that if it is not relevant to the question. The implication is that the scrolling worked until you wanted to add logic to disabl/enable the button. Also you have been given an answer, so don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know that the problem is solved.

Comment: I mentioned that because I didn't know if that thing has any importance or not. If I don't use the "textArea.setCaretPosition(0)", the scroll starts at the bottom when I run the app, that's why I thought it might be ok if I add that to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for changes to the JScrollPane’s viewport, and compare the bottom of the viewport’s visible rectangle with the height of the viewport’s view (that is, the JTextArea):

```
JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();
viewport.addChangeListener(e -> {
    Rectangle rect = viewport.getViewRect();
    int bottom = rect.y + rect.height;
    endButton.setEnabled(bottom >= viewport.getViewSize().height);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! :)